# Multiple instances of same app throws StackOverflow Exception

Tags: c#, wpf, stack-overflow

In my Solution I've 3 main projects (`Server`, `Client` and `Special Client`). In my test environment, (1) `Special Client` just displays a count of Buy/Sell/Executed orders every 5 seconds, (2) `Client` submits Buy/Sell order and (3) `Server` processes the order client submitted and send back to `Client` and `Special Client`. If I launch all 3 Apps by hitting <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd> and let `Client` submit an order every 10 millisecond, all those app work without any problem and on Windows Task Manager I've observed that the memory usage by `Client` fluctuates between 115MB and 320MB, none of those crash (I've tested for long time).

If I launch 2 more `Client` from `../Client/bin/Debug/...` (3 instances of `Client` altogether, 1 `Special Client` and 1 `Server`) and let each `Client` submit 20 orders a second, it also works fine (not sure BUT probably performance of each `Client` deteriorates slightly). If I, however, launch 4th `Client` from `../Client/bin/Debug/...` and let each of them submit 20 orders a second, I eventually get the `StackOverflow exception` on one of those `Client`.

So, in a nutshell, a single `Client` can submit 100 orders/second and get all those back from `Server` and present info on a moderately complex UI without trouble on a single Computer, 3 `Client` together can handle 60 orders/second BUT 4 `Client` together can't handle 80 orders/second!

Why?

### **EDIT**

This is the message I get in Call Stack window:

```
    [External Code] 
>   Client.dll!Client.AsyncObsetion<Data.AllOrder>.OnPropertyChanged(System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventArgs e) Line 29  C#
    [External Code] 
    Client.dll!Client.ClientCode.UpdateOrderOnExecution(Data.AllOrderStruct order) Line 431 C#
    Client.dll!Client.ClientCode.Receive(object sender, System.Net.Sockets.SocketAsyncEventArgs e) Line 390 C#
    Client.dll!Client.ClientCode.Receive(object sender, System.Net.Sockets.SocketAsyncEventArgs e) Line 402 C#
    Client.dll!Client.ClientCode.Receive(object sender, System.Net.Sockets.SocketAsyncEventArgs e) Line 402 C#
    Client.dll!Client.ClientCode.Receive(object sender, System.Net.Sockets.SocketAsyncEventArgs e) Line 402 C#
        .
        .
        .
    Client.dll!Client.ClientCode.Receive(object sender, System.Net.Sockets.SocketAsyncEventArgs e) Line 402 C#
    Client.dll!Client.ClientCode.Receive(object sender, System.Net.Sockets.SocketAsyncEventArgs e) Line 402 C#
    Client.dll!Client.ClientCode.Receive(object sender, System.Net.Sockets.SocketAsyncEventArgs e) Line 402 C#
    [External Code]
```

Line 29 C# refers to this line `else context.Send(RaisePropertyChanged, e);` of this piece of code:

```
public class AsyncObsetion<T> : ObservableCollection<T>
{
    SynchronizationContext context = SynchronizationContext.Current;
    readonly object _lock = new object();
    public AsyncObsetion() { BindingOperations.EnableCollectionSynchronization(this, _lock); }
    public AsyncObsetion(IEnumerable<T> list) : base(list) { BindingOperations.EnableCollectionSynchronization(this, _lock); }

    void RaiseCollectionChanged(object param) => base.OnCollectionChanged((NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs)param);
    void RaisePropertyChanged(object param) => base.OnPropertyChanged((PropertyChangedEventArgs)param);

    protected override void OnCollectionChanged(NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (SynchronizationContext.Current == context) RaiseCollectionChanged(e);
        else context.Send(RaiseCollectionChanged, e);
    }

    protected override void OnPropertyChanged(PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (SynchronizationContext.Current == context) RaisePropertyChanged(e);
        else context.Send(RaisePropertyChanged, e);
    }

    public void InsertRange(IEnumerable<T> items)
    {
        CheckReentrancy();
        foreach (var item in items) Items.Add(item);
        OnCollectionChanged(new NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs(NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Reset));
    }
}
```

BUT I don't have any subscriber in my code for that event! Line 431 refers to this line `if (order.ExType == ExecutionType.Full) list.Remove(o);` this piece of code:

```
void UpdateOrderOnExecution(AllOrderStruct order)
{
    bool buyOrder = order.OrderType == OrderType.Buy;
    var list = buyOrder ? BuyOrders : SellOrders;
    var o = buyOrder ? list.Where(x => x.BuyOrderNo == order.BuyOrderNo).First() : list.Where(x => x.SellOrderNo == order.SellOrderNo).First();
    o.ExType = order.ExType;

    if (order.ExType == ExecutionType.Full) list.Remove(o);
    else
    {
        var index = list.IndexOf(o);
        o.Quantity -= order.QtyTraded;
        list[index] = o;
    }
    AddExecutedOrder(order);
    if (order.BrokerBought == BrokerName || order.BrokerSold == BrokerName) UpDatePendingOrders(o);
    App.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(CommandManager.InvalidateRequerySuggested);
}
```

Line 390 refers to this Line `case Data.Action.Execute: UpdateOrderOnExecution(order); break;` and 402 refers to this line `if (!e.AcceptSocket.ReceiveAsync(e)) Receive(null, e);` of this piece of code:

```
void Receive(object sender, SocketAsyncEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.BytesTransferred > 0 && e.SocketError == SocketError.Success)
    {
        var data = PacMan<MessageHeader>.Unpack(e.Buffer);
        if (data.Type == Message.Trade)
        {
            e.SetBuffer(orderBuffer, 0, orderBuffer.Length);
            e.AcceptSocket.Receive(e.Buffer);
            var order = PacMan<AllOrderStruct>.Unpack(e.Buffer);

            switch (order.Action)
            {
                case Data.Action.Add: AddNewOrder(order); break;
                case Data.Action.Delete: RemoveOrder(order); break;
                case Data.Action.Modify: ModifyOrder(order); break;
                case Data.Action.Execute: UpdateOrderOnExecution(order); break;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            SetBuffer(e, data.Size);
            e.AcceptSocket.Receive(e.Buffer);
            var array = e.Buffer.ToArray();
            Task.Run(() => AddNews(array));
        }

        e.SetBuffer(headerBuffer, 0, headerBuffer.Length);
        if (!e.AcceptSocket.ReceiveAsync(e)) Receive(null, e);
    }
    else Disconnect4mServer(null);
}
```

Comment: post your code that produces a stack overflow

Comment: @Charles, edited the post and [here](https://github.com/EmonHaque/SocketAsyncEventArgs) I've posted the solution as a zip file. Sometime Call Stack Window refers to someother method BUT all those calls originates from `Receive` callback.

Comment: @Charles, To start testing: first, you've to give a name in `TextBox` on lower left corner on Windows with title `Client` and `Special Client`, second click on `Connect` button and third click on `StartTest` Button. To change the interval of automatic submission of order from `Client`: open `ClientCode.cs` of project named `Client`, near the end you'll see `#region MockTest`, there you'll see `void startTest(object obj)` method and change the interval in this line`timer = new DispatcherTimer() { Interval = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 0, 100) };` of that method.

Comment: your problem is the receive function, your pattern to recursive call `receive` endlessly will fail sooner or later. So the solution to your problem is to switch to a iterative solution.

Comment: @Charles, I've found this approach [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.sockets.socketasynceventargs?view=netframework-4.8) and I've same approach on Server side as well. Over the past 2 months I've been working on this and testing this approach BUT never had a crash on Server. Client also never crashed until I added, a kind of, realtime Trade Volume/Price chart (using IMultiValueConverter) on order view, which you can see by clicking on `Order` button.

Comment: @Charles, I've posted my hacky solution in the last EDIT part, I surely can get away with that recursive `Receive` callback.

Comment: yeah, i hope its deprecated, cuz to me its a super ugly pattern. Id just use the sync methods in a new Task / Thread and have some much cleaner code... But your link also doesn't use recursion, so you should consider using some `while (! ReceiveAsync(e)) {...}` instead

Comment: @Charles, I've used Sync, IAsync... and now testing SAEA. To me SAEA is the cleanest and easiest API. In my solution I've used this approach for a file server and client as well, which you can see in project `Updater` and `FileServer.cs` in project `Server`. They've used same recursive pattern, since they've demonstrated with an echo server they splitted the recursion in two methods `ProcessReceive` and `ProcessSend`, otherwise it'd be exactly like what I've done. I believe, this type of recursive call in SAEA actually creates that kind of `while loop` behind the scene.

Answer (score 0):

You should use multithreading approach i dont see any problem in your code because you are using 3 project at the same time try using multithreading and let the cpu handle it for you

Comment: `SocketAsyncEventArgs` by default is multi-threaded, isn't it?

Answer (score 0):

That 'iterative' keyword of **Charles** gave me a hacky Idea. For anyone interested to solve this type of problem, here's my hacky approach with heap:

1) create these three variables in `Client` and `Special Client`:

```
Queue<byte[]> Orders = new Queue<byte[]>();
Timer orderProcessTimer;
bool OPTstarted;
```

2) make changes in `Receive` function in both of those projects to transfer orders to heap and start the `orderProcessTimer` there once by replacing that with these:

```
void Receive(object sender, SocketAsyncEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.BytesTransferred > 0 && e.SocketError == SocketError.Success)
    {
        var data = PacMan<MessageHeader>.Unpack(e.Buffer);
        if (data.Type == Message.Trade)
        {
            e.SetBuffer(orderBuffer, 0, orderBuffer.Length);
            e.AcceptSocket.Receive(e.Buffer);
            Orders.Enqueue(e.Buffer.ToArray());
        }
        else
        {
            SetBuffer(e, data.Size);
            e.AcceptSocket.Receive(e.Buffer);
            AddNews(e.Buffer.ToArray());
        }
        e.SetBuffer(headerBuffer, 0, headerBuffer.Length);
        if (!OPTstarted)
        {
            orderProcessTimer.Start();
            OPTstarted = true;
        }
        if (!e.AcceptSocket.ReceiveAsync(e)) Receive(null, e);
    }
    else Disconnect4mServer(null);
}
```

3) initialize the `orderProcessTimer` in constructor, set processing inverval and hook it into an order processing function:

```
orderProcessTimer = new Timer(500);
orderProcessTimer.Elapsed += ProcessOrder;
```

4) do the time consuming tasks in `ProcessOrder` function:

```
void ProcessOrder(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    orderProcessTimer.Stop();
    var count = Orders.Count;
    if(count > 0)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
        {
            var order = PacMan<AllOrderStruct>.Unpack(Orders.Dequeue());
            switch (order.Action)
            {
                case Data.Action.Add: AddNewOrder(order); break;
                case Data.Action.Delete: RemoveOrder(order); break;
                case Data.Action.Modify: ModifyOrder(order); break;
                case Data.Action.Execute: UpdateOrderOnExecution(order); break;
            }
        }             
    }
    orderProcessTimer.Start();
}
```

`UpdateOrderOnExecution` takes the most of the time for processing a order and making a real time Price-Volume chart in order view.

It works BUT I probably will not go with this approach, I'll make the machine, that runs such type of app, a half-stack machine for the performance.